# How to set tradingView to fit mobile

Tags: javascript, tradingview-api

we have used tradingView in pc Web,and it works just fine.
now we gonna to dev a mobile web.which as I know tradingView is supported.
however,  when I use the demo in GitHub https://github.com/tradingview/charting-library-examples

it looks like the layout and font size are not right.it doesn't support mobile(I've set the resize:true, this may also need some configs with the tooltips?):
[image: demo on my Iphone]

but the demo in official site looks just fine:

[image: demo on official site]

what should I config to support mobile well, thanks 
(I've tried to search this type questions in SO,but got nothing)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add this line in index.html in the public folder

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0">`

https://github.com/tradingview/charting_library/issues/3031

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the `preset`(you can refer to the documentation if you have the access - https://github.com/tradingview/charting_library/wiki/Widget-Constructor#user-content-preset) option value as `"mobile"`  in TradingView widget constructor while initializing it.

> **preset**
>
> preset is a name of predefined widget settings. For now, the only
>   value supported in the preset is mobile.

```
TradingView.onready(function(){
  var widget = window.tvWidget = new TradingView.widget({
    /*
      Your other options
    */
    preset: "mobile"
  };
});
```

A demo look:

[image]